# Jmeter EVENTVALIDATION and VIEWSTATE values passed incorrectly

Tags: jmeter, viewstate, eventvalidation

I need to login a webpage. Passing the parameters from navigation screen,to `POST` to login screen i used `CSS/Jquery` extractor. of the three values extracted, `Viewstate` generator value is passed correctly. But `Eventvalidation` and `Viewstate` has completely different values when passed.

Values i get from Navigating to the website:

```
`VIEWSTATEGENERATORExtractor=C2EE9ACC,VIEWSTATEExtractor=r6PHK0,
EVENTVALIDATIONExtractor=xLhYcNpU3vb8+Om5`      
And passed as VIEWSTATEGENERATOR =C2EE9ACC
EVENTVALIDATION value=Blncm,VIEWSTATE" value=iFpefxx7
```

Some values are generated when passed through but not from previous browser navigation.

DO not understand how 1 value can be passed correctly and not other two. I use same format for all the three

Comment: share the full response and regex expression. There is a chance that there are more than 1 viewstate

Comment: I used CSS/Jquery Extractor with Jsoup:Jquery expression as input[id=__viewstate],Attribute as Value;Match No:1 . When passed as parameter the result i get is  <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="V7gWhPIG" This value is different from what i get in previous request.

Comment: I am struck because some random values are passed between the requests though i use {eventvalidation} reference. It does not pass incorrect values but some random values between the requests and

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole point of viewstate and eventvalidation parameters, they are different **each time**, that's why you need to correlate them for each request.VIEWSTATE has all the information about client-side page state, basically what did the user do on each step. EVENTVALIDATION is a form of [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection, so it has to be different each time as well.

You can validate that your script is doing what it is supposed to be doing using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

References:

- [Page.EnableEventValidation Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx)
- [ASP.NET View State Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks so much Dmitri. But one more clarification So why do we have to pass the Event validation and viewstate as parameters from one step to another?                                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030823/could-not-handle-view-state-and-event-validation-in-jmeter-load-testing